# GraphQL Skip directive - can this be used to exclude items?

Tags: graphql, asp.net-core-webapi

Imagine the following (simplified) GraphQL query:

```
{
    Products {
        Name
        Code
        StockCount
    }
}
```

were to return (say) 50 products, showing the item code, description and the number of items in stock.

The client may not want the items that are out-of-stock to be returned, or they may only be interested in items that have stock less than (say) 50 units.

Now, if this information was all held in the DB, then the sensible thing would of course be to change the SQL statement's where clause to exclude those items.  We'd therefore have to add parameters to the query so that the client can add a cut-off value, and whether they wanted those items with more than, or less than that value.

But, let's imagine that the stock is held in many different locations.  We'd have to query all the different locations and then add the stock quantities together to get the final value, so all the "hard" work has been done before we actually know the answer.  So it's a "computed" value.

What I'm wondering is if the query could be amended to something like either of the following (neither of which seems to work, but hopefully gives you the idea):

```
{
    Products @skip(if: StockCount < 50) {
        Name
        Code
        StockCount
    }
}
```

or

```
query getInStockProducts {
  allProducts
  (where: { {StockCount : {_lt: 50}}})
  {
        Name
        Code
        StockCount
  }
}
```

Comment: `@skip` and `@include` are used to modify the selection set. They are not used to filter what's returned in a list. It's up the server to implement that functionality through arguments.

Comment: @DanielRearden - Hi Daniel, sorry, I probably wasn't clear...I'm aware that `@skip` and `@include` are really for controlling what fields are returned, I just wondered if there was any syntax that would allow what we're after.  I suspect that this has to be provided by additional arguments and the result-set "manually" pruned on the Server before converting into the Graph objects which are returned.  The advantage though would be great  if it were up to the client to decide what they didn't want....

Comment: Sorry if I misread the question. GraphQL has no built-in ways of filtering, sorting, or otherwise manipulating what's returned inside the resolver (beyond field selection). It's up to each service to decide how to do that and implement the appropriate arguments and resolver logic. You can checkout [graphql-lodash](https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-lodash) library for implementing arbitrary manipulation of the results on the client side through directives, but I would caution against using something like that in production.